# No Intellisense in Immediate window

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

VS 2015 Community, Resharper 9

I have no intellisense in the Immediate window in Visual Studio 2015 Community.  I know this was an issue with Resharper in the past but is this still the case?

CTRL+SPACE does not work.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you didn't confuse the *Immediate* window with the *Command* window?

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have the issue of no Intellisense at all in the Immediate Window since I upgraded Resharper. However, I do have to hit `CTRL`+`SPACE` after typing the ful stop to trigger the Intellisense dropdown.

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It can get disabled from a plug-in or whatnot (Resharper).  Here's how to fix it:

***Menu*** -> ***Tools*** -> ***Options*** -> ***Text Editor*** -> ***C#***

No more Control-Space after the dot.